# How to set padding-top for textarea placeholder (but not the normal text)

Tags: html, css

I use a smaller font for the placeholder for input-text and textarea.

The problem is that now the placeholder text in input-text is vertically centered, but the placeholder text in a 1-row textarea is vertically too far on the top.

I tried to use this simple css:

```
textarea::placeholder
{   padding-top: 6px;
}
```

but this seems to have no effect at all.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356268/how-to-set-the-padding-of-placeholder-text) has as a solution to use a padding for the whole textarea, but in that case the padding for entered text would be wrong because it uses a different font-size as the normal text

Comment: Your code works as expected (assuming you have something like `<textarea placeholder="Text"></textarea>`); it shifts the placeholder down and not the normal text. If it does not work for you, you may have rules that override yours. Could you please provide a a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: You can probably use `textarea::placeholder {line-height:200%;}` or so instead.

Comment: line-height does the trick, please provide an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by using a value for "line-height", the exact value has to be found by trial/error, though:

```
textarea::placeholder {line-height:200%;}
```